# Pointwise and uniformly convergence of $f_n(x)=n^{a} x (1-x^2)^{n}$

Tags: real-analysis

I study different cases about $a \in R$ :

If $a=0, f_n(x)=n(1-x^2)^{n}$. If $|x|\le1$ the $\lim_{n\rightarrow +\infty} f_n =0$, in the other case it doesn't esists.
If $a>0$?
$\lim_{n\rightarrow +\infty}n^{a}x(1-x^2)^{n}=0$ for $|x|\le 1$ and not esists for $|x|\ge1$.
Idem per $a<0$

Comment: So what is the question? Find range of $a$ such that $(f_n)_{n=1}^\infty$ converges uniformly?

Comment: Yes.$f_n$ pointwise converge to the function null in [-1,1] $\forall a$

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Uniform convergence of $f_n(x) = n^cx(1-x^2)^n$ on $[0,1]$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/37726/uniform-convergence-of-f-nx-ncx1-x2n-on-0-1)